# Linux Mint 18: xmodmap and third level don't work on firefox and texstudio

Tags: linux-mint, x11, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I'm having problems with keyboard input on two apps: firefox 50.1 and TeXstudio 2.10.8.

I [recently discovered how to enable two keys as 3rd level chooser in Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868546/use-two-keys-for-accessing-3rd-level). The same works for Linux Mint, although no matter what I do the command will not run at session startup. That doesn't really matter, I type the input on a terminal and I can start using them.

I've noticed that before running the xmodmap command I can input text normally in both applications, but as soon as I enter the command on a terminal I loose the ability to type 3rd level symbols; this is problematic since in my keyboard the @ sign is on a 3rd level.

I've checked and after the xmodmap invocation both keys work perfectly well in many other applications (I tested arora, vim, mousepad, gummi, texworks and xfce4-terminal thoroughly). I would like to keep using the left win key as an additional 3rd level chooser because in my keyboard layout the backslash is opposite this key so having this becomes very convenient while typing LaTeX code.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct sequence of commands on bash for this to work is as follows:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 133 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
xmodmap -e 'clear mod4'
```

as per [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=76378). Of course the keycode varies depending on the keyboard layout and one can use xev to know which keycode to use.